# How to clip pandas dataframe in place

Tags: pandas

Unlike numpy, pandas series or dataframe clip() does not seem to have inplace option. For large dataframes, is there a workaround? I tried `np.clip(df.values, -clip_bounds.values, clip_bounds.values, out=df.values)`, but realized that the the values call is expensive as it is doing some merging of blocks underneath.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal `inplace=True` argument.

From [what's New - pandas 0.21.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements):

> DataFrame.clip() and Series.clip() have gained an inplace argument. 
>   ([GH15388](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15388))

So from now on, you can use the following to clip values between 0 and 1:

```
df.clip(lower=0, upper=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
df[df > x] = x
```

Comment: I assume df>x will create something that's the same size as df?

Comment: df> x is locating the values in df greater than clip value x to be replaced.  you could use df < x too.  df [df> clip_value] = clip_value is same thing. Hope this works in your case.

Comment: I probably should make my question clearer -- my ultimate goal is to speed up the clipping. I agree that your suggestion achieved "in-place", but in the process it creates df>x which is a dataframe the same shape as df. So I suspect that it will not be any faster than df = df.clip(x).