# Limiting values of column to +100% in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have columns in df whose values should be limited to +100%

Current output:

```
var1  var2   var3    var4
140%  475%   895%   16249%
337% -100%  -100%    -100%
173%  -95%  5165%     454%
458%   18%   354%    -100%
483%  -73%  6962%    -100%
147%   18%  -100%    -100%
```

Desired output

```
var1  var2   var3    var4
100%  100%   100%     100%
100% -100%  -100%    -100%
100%  -95%   100%     100%
100%   18%   100%    -100%
100%  -73%   100%    -100%
100%   18%  -100%    -100%
```

So each value in each column which higher than 100%, should be replaced with 100%.
And I don't know how to do it

EDIT: data is not strings, but previously looked like this:

Previous output:

```
var1  var2   var3    var4
1.40  4.75   8.95   162.49
3.37 -1.00  -1.00    -1.00
1.73 -0.95  51.65     4.54
4.58  0.18   3.54    -1.00
4.83 -0.73  69.62    -1.00
1.47  0.18  -1.00    -1.00
```

on which I applied this:

```
df = df.style.format({'var1': '{:.0%}','var2': '{:.0%}', 'var3': '{:.0%}','var4': '{:.0%}'})
```

as I need numbers in % as final output

Big apologies for not providing sufficient info, and thank you very much for your help @user19077881

Comment: Consider providing a minimum, reproducible example:
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @KevinMc take a look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clip pandas dataframe in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216842/how-to-clip-pandas-dataframe-in-place)

Answer (score 2):

To apply numpy clip to a DataFrame df with the % values as strings you could use:

```
def clip_it(x):
    try:
        n = x.replace('%', '')
        n = np.clip(int(n), -100, 100)
        return str(n)+'%'
    except ValueError:
        return x
```

df = df.applymap(clip_it)

with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['100%', '-200%', '57%'],
                   'y': [ '45%', '167%', '-23%']})
```

it gives

```
       x     y
0   100%   45%
1  -100%  100%
2    57%  -23%
```

Comment: I'm getting error: "TypeError: 'Styler' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Try using the DF styler AFTER converting the DF values to the clipped values you want. So checking that the conversion works on the 'unadorned' DF, My code assumed that the values were strings ending with % so if that is not so then the code would need adjusting.

Comment: Do you have a Dataframe or a Styler?! **Always make the datatype explicit in your question.** This answer works with a df, so you may want to use it before creating the Styler.

Comment: I used following before. df = df.style.format({'val1': '{:.0%}','val2': '{:.0%}',
                                                'val3': '{:.0%}','val4': '{:.0%}'})

Comment: [`style` returns a Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.style.html).

Comment: I get different error when applying before styler: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: This suggests all your elements are not in the format you described. I edited the code to respond to the error so you can try and sort out where the problem is.

Comment: @user19077881, sorry for causing problems, and thank you very much for trying to help me. it didn't occur to me that those could be viewed as strings.. those were floats, which made multiple blockages to proposed solution. which again (if styler is remover) gives AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'.

Comment: @user19077881 styler multiplied values by 100 and added %

Comment: You can still use applymap. Just delete the replace line, return only the number and change the clip line to `n = np.clip(n, -100.0, 100.0)`. You maybe need to change the 100 limits as well. I could edit the code if you define the limits for the clip before Styler applied. the reason I assumed strings is that is because of the % and not knowing you had used Styler.

Comment: I added previous data, before applying styler. I need output to be numbers, as next step is graph :/
Big thanks once again @user19077881

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clip your data to `-100%, 100%`, you should do it before styling it. Because your styler is basically multiplying by 100 and adding a '%' character, a `-100%, 100%` clip in your styled data is equivalent to a `-1.0, 1.0` clip in your original data.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.clip(x, -1, 1))
df

    var1    var2    var3    var4
0   1.0     1.00    1.0    1.0
1   1.0    -1.00   -1.0   -1.0
2   1.0    -0.95    1.0    1.0
3   1.0     0.18    1.0   -1.0
4   1.0    -0.73    1.0   -1.0
5   1.0     0.18   -1.0   -1.0

df.style.format({'var1': '{:.0%}','var2': '{:.0%}', 'var3': '{:.0%}','var4': '{:.0%}'})

    var1    var2    var3    var4
0   100%    100%    100%    100%
1   100%   -100%   -100%   -100%
2   100%   -95%     100%    100%
3   100%    18%     100%   -100%
4   100%   -73%     100%   -100%
5   100%    18%    -100%   -100%
```

However, I wonder whether you actually nedd to *clip* your data as your example suggest or whether you may want to scale it relative to the maximum and minimum in each column. If you clip it, you loss the differences between 162.49 and 4.54, both becoming 100%. By scaling it, you can keep it in the desired range while conserving the relative distances.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50028155/15032126), you can do

```
def scaler(data):
    top, bottom = 1, -1
    minimum, maximum = data.min(), data.max()
    return (data - maximum) / (minimum - maximum) * (bottom - top) + top

df = df.apply(scaler)
df

    var1    var2    var3    var4
0  -1.000000    1.000000   -0.718210    1.000000
1   0.148688   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000
2  -0.807580   -0.982609    0.491079   -0.932228
3   0.854227   -0.589565   -0.871425   -1.000000
4   1.000000   -0.906087    1.000000   -1.000000
5  -0.959184   -0.589565   -1.000000   -1.000000

df.style.format({'var1': '{:.0%}','var2': '{:.0%}', 'var3': '{:.0%}','var4': '{:.0%}'})


    var1    var2    var3    var4
0  -100%    100%    -72%    100%
1    15%   -100%   -100%   -100%
2   -81%    -98%     49%    -93%
3    85%    -59%    -87%   -100%
4   100%    -91%    100%   -100%
5   -96%    -59%   -100%   -100%
```

Of course, because this is scaling based on the max and min values of each column, while clipping on `-1.0, 1.0`, the 0 of the scaled data is not going to correspond with the 0 of the original data. For example, in the column `var4`, 4.54 becomes -93% because is really close tot the minimum. You can adapt the previous function to use the maximum absolute value when scaling:

```
def scaler_abs(data):
    top, bottom = 1, -1
    max_abs = max([data.min(), data.max()], key=abs)
    minimum, maximum = -max_abs, max_abs
    return (data - maximum) / (minimum - maximum) * (bottom - top) + top

df = df.apply(scaler_abs)
df

    var1    var2    var3    var4
0   0.289855    1.000000    0.128555    1.000000
1   0.697723   -0.210526   -0.014364   -0.006154
2   0.358178   -0.200000    0.741885    0.027940
3   0.948240    0.037895    0.050847   -0.006154
4   1.000000   -0.153684    1.000000   -0.006154
5   0.304348    0.037895   -0.014364   -0.006154

df.style.format({'var1': '{:.0%}','var2': '{:.0%}', 'var3': '{:.0%}','var4': '{:.0%}'})

    var1    var2    var3    var4
0   29%     100%     13%     100%
1   70%     -21%     -1%      -1%
2   36%     -20%     74%       3%
3   95%       4%      5%      -1%
4   100%    -15%    100%      -1%
5   30%       4%     -1%      -1%
```

Answer (score -1):

You might use [`numpy.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to set values outside range with range min or max, consider following simple example

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[-500,-300,-100],[0,50,150]])
arr2 = np.clip(arr, -100, 100)
print(arr2)
```

gives output

```
[[-100 -100 -100]
 [   0   50  100]]
```